# Is it possible to get dataset file infromation at the time of test a model?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

My dataset code is like the below one; Here, `X_test` is a `list[list]` and `y_test` is `list[Path]`

The `first.py` file

```
self.test_dataset = LongDataset(
                X_path=X_test,
                y_path=y_test,
                transform=val_transforms,
            )
```

The rest of the part is as usual (`dataloader`)

```
def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.test_dataset, batch_size=1, num_workers=8)
```

In the `second.py` file

The `DataModule`

```
data_module = DataModuleLong(batch_size=3,)
```

The `Trainer`

```
trainer = Trainer(gpus=1)
    trainer.test(
        model=model,
        ckpt_path=ckpt_path,
        datamodule=data_module,
    )
```

The  `train_step()` in the `third.py` file

```
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx: int):
        inputs, targets = batch
        logits = self(inputs)
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Now, is it possible to print (in the `train_step()`) the (`inputs, targets`) filename (or the full path) I am sending from `test_dataset` as (`X_path`, `y_path`)?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what you want to do is get the index of each batch element in the batch returned by the `dataloader` object (from there it is trivial to index the dataset to get the desired data elements (in this case file paths).

Now the short answer is that there is no directly implemented way to return this data using the dataloader. However, there are a few workarounds:

- Pass your own `BatchSampler` or `Sampler` object to the `DataLoader` constructor. Unfortunately there's not a simple way to query the `Sampler` for the current batch because it relies on generators (where yielding the next sample clears it and loades the next one. This is the same reason why you can't directly access the batch indices of the `Dataloader`. So to use this method, you'd have to pass a sampler wherein you know *a priori* which indices will be returned on the i-th query to the sampler. Not an ideal solution.
- Create a custom dataset object - this is actually extremely easy to do, simply inherit from the `torch.data` object and implement the `__init__`, `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods. The `__getitem__` method takes an index (let's say `idx`) as input and returns that index of the dataset. You can essentially copy the code for the existing `LongDataset` line for line, but simply append `idx` to the returned values from the `__getitem__` method. I would demonstrate but you don't indicate where the `LongDataset` code comes from.

  ```
  def __getitem__(self,idx):
      ... #load files, preprocess, etc.
      return data, idx
  ```

  Now dataloader will automatically zip the `idx` values for each, so you can simply replace the existing line with:

  ```
  inputs, targets, indices = batch
  data_paths = [self.test_dataset.file_paths[idx] for idx in indices]
  ```

**The second solution is by far preferable as it is more transparently easy to understand.**

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation. I do have `def __getitem__(self, I):` and I am returning `return X_img, y_img` from this function

Comment: Does it mean, if I use `return X_img, y_img, I)` and later I can get it here `inputs, targets, indices = batch`?

Comment: Yes, the name of the indexing variable within `__getitem__` is arbitrary. Dataloader takes essentially a list of `batch_size` return values of the dataset  (each of which will now be a 3-tuple of `X_img`, `y_img` and `I`), and zips them up into 3 lists or tensors each of length `batch_size`

Comment: So I am getting `AttributeError: 'LitModel' object has no attribute 'test_dataset'`. This is my model class `LitModel`. I am not sure this is happening because I have multiple files. Like, `test_dataset` and `test_dataloader` in the first.py file, `Trainer` in the second.py file and `test_step()` in the third.py file. Third file also contains the `LitModel` class.

Comment: Well, this is caused by the fact that the dataset is not an attribute of the model and you do not pass the dataset object itself to the `test_step` method. You can pass the dataset as another parameter, or you can separate the indices from `batch` before passing to `test_step`. In short, your problem is an issue of variable scope

Comment: If you want more specific help, you'll need to post more of your code as some important sections are missing right now

Comment: would you mind telling me which portion of code should I post?

Comment: code that calls `test step`, code that assigns a batch to variable `batch`, the definition of `LongDataset` and where you create a `LongDataset` object in your code. In short, think about how someone would diagnose the problem. Also unclear what `DataModuleLong` is or does, as it is not shown anywhere else in the posted code